# Why does summing the rows in this matrix give me 0?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, sum

I created an array `A` by first using the command `A = [1:10]'`.
Then I created a 10x10 matrix, only containing 0's. I then overwrote this matrix with my `A`, resulting in this new matrix:

```
A =

     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     7     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     8     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     9     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Now the problem is, when I run the command `sum((A(1,1)):(A(1,end)))`, I keep getting 0 when I should be getting 1, as it is the sum of the first row. I tried running the same command on other matrices and they give me the correct answer, so why isn't it working here?

Comment: If you want the sum of the first row, you can just use `sum(A(1, :))` 
your expression will translate to `sum((1):(0))`

Comment: What you meant is probably `sum((A(1,1:end)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term

```
(A(1,1)):(A(1,end))
```

creates and empty array, as `A(1,1) = 1` and `A(1,end) = 0` which makes it impossible for [**`colon :`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) to create a vector, so the sum over it is zero. But its not what you want anyway, I guess.

What you supposedly want is

```
sum(A(1,:))
```

or in respect to whole matrix, by specifying the dimension of the sum, e.g.

```
sum(A,2)

ans =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10
```

### Edit

If you want to start from a different column index you can do the following:

```
sum( A(rowIndex,firstColumnIndex:lastColumnIndex) )
```

while `end` can be used as macro variable for the last index of the corresponding column or row.

Comment: Ahh, I see thank you! However, I am running a loop to add numbers in each row, not from the beginning though, that's only for the first row. How would I sum the remaining numbers in a row, starting at any point along the row?